# Play sound on server when link is clicked

Tags: php, html, ubuntu-14.04

Here's what we are trying to do:

We have a podcast and there are 4 of us that want to play sounds on our SFX track. We have the computer set up and it goes into our feed nicely, but we want to have a common page that has our bank of sounds (music, bumpers/intros, etc). What I am having a bear of a time trying to figure out is:

When someone clicks a link, how do we get the server to play the sound, and not the device connected to the web page.

The flow is:

User clicks a link - and the sound plays on the server/computer that is connected to the mixer.

How might we go about setting this up? We are running a LAMP stack on an Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

a few options:

- setup [Growl](http://growl.info/)
- fire off an email and setup an email filter/alert
- [set up a service that monitors a directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43846/how-to-put-a-trigger-on-a-directory) for new files and performs an action...  write a file to monitored directory
- [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) + https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayMusicFromCommandLine
- write to file or database.... poll said database every x seconds via a webpage/ajax that uses any javascript audio library to play sound